# Where I Can Paste Piwik JS Code In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

I need to integrate piwik for my Site. where i can paste my piwik java-script to my magento.

Work-Out :: Copy and paste to SYSTEM->CONFIGURATION->GENERAL->DESIGN->Miscellaneous Scripts-> here

But its not working

How can i properly insert js to my magento.

Comment: did you clear cache? see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150339/adding-my-javascript-code-in-magento/150342#150342

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov : Yes i cleared and re-indexed but not working

Comment: if you open up HTML source code in the browser do you see your js code there?

Answer (score 0):

The most complex and fexible solution would be to use Magento's Google Tag Manager integration (example tutorial https://www.branchlabs.com/magento-development/how-to-set-up-google-tag-manager-for-magento ) and use GTM to paste Piwik JS.
Google Tag Manager integration will allow you to rule all your tracking codes from one simple interface.