# Adding my javascript code in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu

In my project I have hamburger menu to show up the menu list for Ecommerce site. But I have tried in normal php site it works fine, but I am confused where to put the javascript code in Magento site. I am using the magento version 1.9.3

[image]

Even I tried this code in layout.xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/nav.js</name><params/></action>
```

Can anyone help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want it to be merged with other magento scripts you can add Javascript to

*System > Configuration > Design > Html Head > Miscellaneous Scripts*

or

*System > Configuration > Design > Footer > Miscellaneous HTML*

no need to bother with layout files if you don't want to

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me has per the answer.

Comment: Sorry your answer works for me. I forgot to clear up the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your layout.xml file.

```
<default>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script_name.js</name></action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

**script_name.js** file located :

> skin/frontend/{Theme Package Name}/{Theme Name}/js/script_name.js

Comment: I tried this method but it didn't display it

Comment: Add your layout xml code or js path. above code is working and tested.